# I would like to generate a $\mathbb{Z}^5$ lattice with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

The image shows a way to generate $\mathbb{Z}^3$ lattice and a $\mathbb{Z}^2$ lattice.

The coordinates from the cube vertices are

(-2,-2,-2)

(-1,-2,-2)

...

( 2, 2, 2)

and from the plane vertices

(-2,-2,0)

(-1,-2,0)

...

( 2, 2, 0)

However, I need a $\mathbb{Z}^5$ lattice. Is there a possibility to combine every vertex of the plane with every vertex of the cube to obtain something like this:

(-2,-2,-2) (-2,-2,0)

(-1,-2,-2) (-2,-2,0)

...

( 2, 2, 2) (2, 2, 0)

In mathematics this operation is called direct product, but I have no glue how to set this up in geometry nodes. All the following operations would act on the set of all possible five tuples. I hope that this is not too technical.

[image]

Comment: How would you like to output the result ? Right now, I am thinking of instancing the plane at each vertex of the cube. Choosing a vertex of the cube will give you the first part (i,j,k). Then choosing a vertex of the plane will give you the second part (l,m). But I am in the dark about how you could use this...

Comment: Another approach is to create a 5^5=3125 point cloud, then to decode the index n as n=(i+2)+5*{(j+2)+5*[(k+2)+5*{(l+2)+5*(m+2)}]} (more or less...)

Comment: I'm not in the mood to look up any formulas, but I guess there surely are formulas to calculate this "by hand". So it should be possible to setup _Vector Math_ and _Math_ nodes probably with the help of _Separate XYZ_ and _Combine XYZ_ nodes to recreate this step by step. I mean, people are also recreating fractals and Aizawa strange attractors with _Math_ nodes so I guess it is just a matter of knowing the formulas.

Comment: I think the point cloud will do the job. This is great!

Comment: If the point-cloud does it.. I'd be intrigued to see the mechanics. I hope one of you writes it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Let $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $i, j, k, l, m \in [-K,K] \cap \mathbb{Z}$.
Let $B$ such that $B=2K+1$.

The tuple $(i,j,k,l,m)$ is encoded in the index $n$ as:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
  n & = & 1 \times (i+K) \\
    & + & B \times (j+K) \\
    & + & B^2 \times (k+K) \\
    & + & B^3 \times (l+K) \\
    & + & B^4 \times (m+K)
  \end{array}$$

To decode $n$, a recursive process is used. Let $I^t-K$ stands for $i,j,k,l,m$ with $t=0,1,2,3,4$ respectively. Let $N^t$ such that $N^t=I^t+B \times N^{t+1}$, with $N^0=n$. Then:

$$ I^t = N^t \ \mathrm{mod} \ B $$
$$ N^{t+1} = \frac{N^t - I^t}{B} $$

[image: GN graph - Main]

**1.** $K$ is set to $2$.
**2.** A *Point Cloud* of $B^5$ points is initialized.
**3.** $(i,j,k)$ are stored in a first vector.
**4.** $(l,m)$ are stored in a second vector.

[image: GN graph - Recursive relation]

**1.** *NodeGroup* computing $I^t$ and updating $N^t$.

Resources: [image]

Answer (score 0):

The hint from

[@StefLAncien](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpMxV.png)

with the point cloud helped to solve the problem. The following solution generates $\mathbb{Z}^5$ vectors. The range $r$ determines the maximal absolute value for components of the the vector. It must be smaller than 9. So at most vectors from (-9,-9,-9,-9,-9) to (9,9,9,9,9) can be created.

To achieve this a point cloud of the size $b^5$ with $b=(2r+1)$ is created. The index $i$ is mapped into the vector $(d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5)$ according to the following rule: $$ i = (d_1-r) \cdot b^4+(d_2-r)\cdot b^4+(d_3-r)\cdot b^2+(d_4-r)\cdot b+(d_5-r) $$

This map is performed in the node "Index2Tuple" which is displayed in a separate image. To make the result visible the 5-tuples are split into a 3-dimensional vector and a 2-dimensional one. This yields two sets of points shown in the images for $r-3$ and $r-5$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Resource: [image]